# VirtualHost with Multiple Domains Not Serving Correct DocumentRoot

Tags: linux, virtualhost, apache2

Running CentOS 6, Apache.

I have the following in my httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName domain1.example
    ServerAlias www.domain1.example
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2
    ServerName domain2.example
    ServerAlias www.domain2.example
</VirtualHost>
```

Whenever I visit `domain2.example` (or `www.domain2.example`), I am shown `domain1.example`.

EDIT: More info from `httpd.conf`

```
Listen 80
#NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Things I have checked:

- Apache has been restarted
- DNS for `domain1.example` and `domain2.example` point to same IP

What am I missing?

**SOLUTION:**

As Patrick points out, in Apache 2.2, `NameVirtualHost` is required when using multiple `VirtualHost`s. The solution here was to uncomment the line in `httpd.conf`:

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80
```

to:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment: Is this apache 2.2 or 2.4?  You might consider moving domain2.com DocumentRoot into it's own directory that is not in /var/www/html

Comment: Apache 2.2. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You are not showing everything. What is your `NameVirtualHost` and `Listen` directives? Does the DNS resolution works correctly from the server and the client querying it?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek added more info. `NameVirtualHost` is commented out. Is this necessary in this situation? Every example I've seen on the web doesn't specify this being on.

Comment: Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost : "Prior to 2.3.11, NameVirtualHost was required to instruct the server that a particular IP address and port combination was usable as a name-based virtual host. In 2.3.11 and later, any time an IP address and port combination is used in multiple virtual hosts, name-based virtual hosting is automatically enabled for that address."  You are on 2.2 so `NameVirtualHost` is mandatory in your case...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek you are correct, sir. Thanks for that. If you can make your solution an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using only Apache 2.2 you absolutely need to use the `NameVirtualHost` directive in order to let Apache know that you have multiple websites under different names but with the same IP.

The directive became deprecated in Apache 2.3, as written in this documentation: httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

> Prior to 2.3.11, NameVirtualHost was required to instruct the server that a particular IP address and port combination was usable as a name-based virtual host. In 2.3.11 and later, any time an IP address and port combination is used in multiple virtual hosts, name-based virtual hosting is automatically enabled for that address.

For your version, the guide on configuration name based virtual host is here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html#using

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's matching to the first vhost.

Try something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Is there an alternative to moving the entire docroot? `domain1` is a live prod server. Is there any explanation for why the first vhost is matching when a different domain is requested?

Comment: @ChrisTanner : have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html#using